# CMake is Unable to Compile a Simple Test Program in CLion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, cuda, clion

I am using CLion and have been for a long time now and I have had no issues with it until recently. I was trying to get CUDA to work in CLion but was unable to make any progress. I asked a question on stack overflow but had no answers, though some comments did alter the error slightly to the point where it appears to be a linker error, though I am not entirely sure.

The comments suggested the following:

1. Switch from GCC (Through Cygwin) to MSVC
2. Use a 64 bit project as opposed to a 32 bit one
3. Use MSVC 2017 rather than 2019
4. Set the CMake flag `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10`

These did alter the error mesage I was getting and it appeared to be simpler, though I am still no closer to fixing the issue. I have noticed, however, that MSVC gives a very similar error (both 2019 and 2017) except it names `cl.exe` rather than `nvcc`.

I know that CUDA works on my PC as I am able to compile, run and profile programs successfully.
I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit with an RTX 2080 SUPER graphics card.

This is the error message I get:

```
C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.7846.88\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10 -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C-Cpp\CUDA_TEST
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.0.194
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/penci/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/201.7846.88/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:46 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/C-Cpp/CUDA_TEST/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_8c901\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir\build
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c901.dir/main.cu.obj
        C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v11.0\bin\nvcc.exe    -D_WINDOWS -Xcompiler=" /GR /EHsc"  -Xcompiler="-Zi -Ob0 -Od /RTC1" -Xcompiler=-MDd -x cu -c C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C-Cpp\CUDA_TEST\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\main.cu -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir\main.cu.obj -Xcompiler=-FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir\,-FS
    main.cu
    Linking CUDA executable cmTC_8c901.exe
        C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.7846.88\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo "CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir\main.cu.obj"  @C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\Temp\nm4A7B.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir\main.cu.obj /out:cmTC_8c901.exe /implib:cmTC_8c901.lib /pdb:C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C-Cpp\CUDA_TEST\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_8c901.pdb /version:0.0 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/lib/x64 cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c901.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
       Creating library cmTC_8c901.lib and object cmTC_8c901.exp
    MSVCRTD.lib(utility_app.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RoInitialize referenced in function __scrt_initialize_winrt
    cmTC_8c901.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.7846.88\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/C-Cpp/CUDA_TEST/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/C-Cpp/CUDA_TEST/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

============================ EDIT ============================

This is the error I get with MSVC 2019. It is very similar but not quite the same

```
C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.7846.88\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10 -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C-Cpp\CUDA_TEST
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.0.194
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/penci/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/201.7846.88/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:46 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/C-Cpp/CUDA_TEST/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_e8010\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir\build
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e8010.dir/main.cu.obj
        C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v11.0\bin\nvcc.exe    -D_WINDOWS -Xcompiler=" /GR /EHsc"  -Xcompiler="-Zi -Ob0 -Od /RTC1" -Xcompiler=-MDd -x cu -c C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C-Cpp\CUDA_TEST\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\main.cu -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir\main.cu.obj -Xcompiler=-FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir\,-FS
    main.cu
    Linking CUDA executable cmTC_e8010.exe
        C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.7846.88\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo "CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir\main.cu.obj"  @C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\Temp\nmE086.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir\main.cu.obj /out:cmTC_e8010.exe /implib:cmTC_e8010.lib /pdb:C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C-Cpp\CUDA_TEST\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_e8010.pdb /version:0.0 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/lib/x64 cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_e8010.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
       Creating library cmTC_e8010.lib and object cmTC_e8010.exp
    MSVCRTD.lib(utility_app.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RoInitialize referenced in function __scrt_initialize_winrt
    cmTC_e8010.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\penci\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.7846.88\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/C-Cpp/CUDA_TEST/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/C-Cpp/CUDA_TEST/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

Comment: "Use MSVC 2017 rather than 2019" - That would be a step backwards, why would you do that?

Comment: Apparently CUDA doesn’t work for later versions?

Comment: The exact requirements for which VS and tool versions are supported in CUDA 11 are fully documented in the Windows installation documentation

Comment: Switching to MSVC 2019 still gives me an error. I have added it to the question now